# The answer is a single letter

Tags: cryptic-clues

As the title says, the answer to this entire puzzle is just one letter, but I'll want to see how you get to it. The clues are below:

> Also a group
>   Check out the reason why
>   Move gently to disappear
>   Chase after a little money
>   Stores quality finds
>   My own storage space
>   Health club fight
>   Hold onto a grudge
>   Round and around
>   Trolley identification

Comment: Are you *sure* the cryptic-clues tag is correct? Note that it doesn't just mean "clues that are cryptic" but refers to a particular *kind* of cryptic clues, namely those found in cryptic crosswords.

Comment: It was the closest tag I could find, and the clues are *almost* like what you'd find in a cryptic crossword.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's not far off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the single letter answer is:

> R

Each line appears to be

> A clue to two words that have a one letter difference.

Also a group

> **b**and

Check out the reason why

> ca**u**se

Move gently to disappear

> e**r**ase (From [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53704/the-answer-is-a-single-letter/53719?noredirect=1#comment166036_53719))

Chase after a little money

> spe**n**d

Stores quality finds

> ca**t**ches (From [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53704/the-answer-is-a-single-letter/53719?noredirect=1#comment166021_53719))

My own storage space

> s**h**elf

Health club fight

> spa**r** (From [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53704/the-answer-is-a-single-letter#comment165985_53706))

Hold onto a grudge

> grip**e**

Round and around

> **a**bout

Trolley identification

> car**d**

Putting all of them together:

> burn thread, which is another clue as above:
>  st**r**ing (Thanks to [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53704/the-answer-is-a-single-letter/53719?noredirect=1#comment166036_53719))

Comment: That looks promising! I think the chase / little money may be (s)cent and the stores / finds ca(t)ches. This would give bu.s / thread and maybe there's a st(r)ing there somewhere.

Comment: All the ones that seem clearly right have the short word first, then the long. That argues against both PURS(U)E and (S)CENT.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan's observation is probably correct. If "thread" is one part of the overall clue, the S makes grammatical agreement less likely. I haven't got anything better to offer for the chase, but I believe that the overall clue is "Burn thread" with an obvious answer. The 3rd answer could then be e(r)ase, although to erase means to _make_ disappear.

Comment: At a stretch, there's also dồ**n**g (Vietnamese coin) and dog (to pursue).

Comment: You are correct! Mostly. Walt got my intended answer for the fourth clue - it is indeed do(n)g. Also, I had a different intended final answer, but I actually like yours/M Oehm's better. (And "disappear" may be colloquially used as a verb in some contexts ...)

Comment: @ConMan Was the intended solution [link-as-spoiler](http://fire.and.fibre)?

Comment: That's the one!

Answer (score 4):

Also a group

> Band

Check out the reason why

> Basis

Move gently to disappear

> Blend

Chase after a little money

> Beg

Stores quality finds

> Batch

My own storage space

> Bag

Health club fight

> Billiards

Hold onto a grudge

> Badmouth

Round and around

> Boundary

Trolley identification

> Badge

The answer is

> letter B

Comment: The description of the puzzle says one /single letter is the answer !

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay the answer is a riddle itself, can you solve it? ;-)

Comment: Well, @whirlwin, I provided my answer ... pls. check.

Comment: Ooh, good ones! I was thinking "boxing" for health club fight, too.

Answer (score 1):

The character is

> 'R'

Also a group

> 'R' pronounced like 'Our' which denote a group

Check out the reason why

> 'R' is a starting letter of 'Reason' and 'WHY?' is also a Rock Band which start with 'R'

Move gently to disappear

> 'Remove' starts with 'R' that means to remove the things

Chase after a little money

> Could be 'Ransom' against a kidnapping which starts with 'R'.

Stores quality finds

> 'Refrigeration' that start with 'R'

My own storage space

> 'ROM' of a computer device, that denotes its own space to store data and also start with 'R'

Health club fight

> Health club fight provided for our own 'Resistance' training and also start with 'R'

Hold onto a grudge

> It could brings the 'Resentment' and that start with 'R'

Round and around

> 'Round' is the common word and it start with 'R'

Trolley identification

> It uses the RFID chip which start with 'R'

Comment: Hmmm. I also thought about R, but because, for example, "Health club fight" could be spa and spaR. And the different character of round and around is surely A, not R?

Comment: I have changed a bit and common between around and round is 'Round' and that start with 'R' too.

Comment: An interesting idea, but no, there is more to it than just starting letters (or sound-alikes).

Comment: But the answer is 'R'?

Comment: I like @MOehm's idea so 'Trolley identification'  → cart/e ( Round and around → a/bout also works with same result).

Answer (score 0):

The letter is

> Q

1. Also a group

   > Queue
2. Check out the reason why

   > Question
3. Move gently to disappear

   > Queue
4. Chase after a little money

   > Quotes
5. Stores quality finds
6. My own storage space
7. Health club fight
8. Hold onto a grudge
9. Round and around
10. Trolley identification

Answer (score -1):

Is the answer

> i ?!

As the explanation goes here:

Also a group

> A rockband callded EYE (is a NY based band, pronounced the same as the single letter) exist(ed)!

Check out the reason why

> Usually an introspection (for reasoning why) statrts with one's self / i

Move gently to disappear

> Close your eye gently to make the things disappear

Chase after a little money

> The little money is interest, usually denoted by letter 'i'.

Stores quality finds

> Usually useful information is gathered and displayed with letter 'i'.

My own storage space

> In Apple poducts storage space is denoted by 'i', such as iCloud!

Health club fight

> To be checked ...no information...

Hold onto a grudge

> Grudges are usually caused due to EGO, which is the reason for holding/keeping a grudge alive, for which the cause is 'i'.

Round and around

> EYE / i can go round and around remaining the same !

Trolley identification

> Trolley's location is usually identified at 'i' center